# AJAX and jQuery trigger setInterval on click to update rendered XML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two scripts, the first one loads a particular set of child nodes from an XML file via AJAX in order to render a menu in the form of a list of buttons in `#loadMe`. The great thing about this first script is that I have implemented the `setInterval` function which updates the list of buttons automatically anytime the XML file changes. The first script's rendered buttons are written to trigger the second script on mouse click, which renders a `div` filled with the desired node's sibling nodes in `#toadMe`. This second script also works, but only upon mouse click does it ensure updated data. In other words the `setInterval` function does not work on the second script because it is expecting a mouse click. How do I make the second script auto update if once it is displayed via mouse click?

```
    setInterval(itemMenu,1500);

    function itemMenu() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "people.xml"
        }).done(function (xml) {

            $("#loadMe").empty();

            $(xml).find('fullName').each(function() {
                var fullName = $(this).text();
                $('<button type="button" onclick="itemContent(this.value)"></button>').attr('value', fullName).html(fullName).appendTo('#loadMe');
            });
        }).fail(function (response, error) {
            $('#info').text('Error!');
        });

    };


    //setInterval(itemContent,1500);

    function itemContent(q) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "people.xml"

        }).done(function (xml) {

            $(xml).find('fullName').each(function() {

                var fullName = $(this).text();

                if(q==fullName) {

                    $("#toadMe").empty();
                    firstName = $(this).siblings('firstName');
                    lastName = $(this).siblings('lastName');
                    age = $(this).siblings('age');
                    hometown = $(this).siblings('hometown');
                    job = $(this).siblings('job');

                    $('<h1></h1>').html(firstName).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(lastName).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(age).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(hometown).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(job).appendTo('#toadMe');
                }

            });

        }).fail(function (response, error) {

            $('#info').text('Error!');

        });

    };
```

Comment: Why can't you just update it after the ajax call, calling itemContent(fullname) in the first script?

Comment: Panama @Panama Jack Because I don't want to load everything initially. I only want to load particular sibling nodes upon request. Is this a good reason? I thought it would be unnecessary to do extra loads for data that is hidden initially anyway. Your suggestion does the opposite. Am I right? Or do you mean something else? Thanks.

Comment: How do you want the 2nd script to autoupdate? Immediately after the ajax call?

Comment: @PanamaJack, no only after the corresponding buttons have been clicked. The 2nd script already autoupdates upon click, initially, on each click. But I want the displayed data to also autoupdate while its being displayed, not just once the button has been clicked. How can I do this? Thanks a lot Jack.

Comment: Still a little confused. so itemMenu() displays the data correct? on set intevral and updates the link? But you also want the data you received from itemMenu() to be displayed using itemContent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
setInterval(itemMenu,1500);

    function itemMenu() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "people.xml"
        }).done(function (xml) {

            $("#loadMe").empty();

            $(xml).find('fullName').each(function() {
                var fullName = $(this).text();
                $('<button type="button" onclick="itemContent(this.value)"></button>').attr('value', fullName).html(fullName).appendTo('#loadMe');
                 itemContent(fullName);
            });
        }).fail(function (response, error) {
            $('#info').text('Error!');
        });

    };


    //setInterval(itemContent,1500);

    function itemContent(q) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "people.xml"

        }).done(function (xml) {

            $(xml).find('fullName').each(function() {

                var fullName = $(this).text();

                if(q==fullName) {

                    $("#toadMe").empty();
                    firstName = $(this).siblings('firstName');
                    lastName = $(this).siblings('lastName');
                    age = $(this).siblings('age');
                    hometown = $(this).siblings('hometown');
                    job = $(this).siblings('job');

                    $('<h1></h1>').html(firstName).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(lastName).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(age).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(hometown).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(job).appendTo('#toadMe');
                }

            });

        }).fail(function (response, error) {

            $('#info').text('Error!');

        });

    };
```

Or you can create use another function so that you don't have to make another ajax call and  something like this.

```
setInterval(itemMenu,1500);

    function itemMenu() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "people.xml"
        }).done(function (xml) {

            $("#loadMe").empty();

            $(xml).find('fullName').each(function() {
                var fullName = $(this).text();
                $('<button type="button" onclick="itemContent(this.value)"></button>').attr('value', fullName).html(fullName).appendTo('#loadMe');
                 update($(this));
            });
        }).fail(function (response, error) {
            $('#info').text('Error!');
        });

    };

       function update(obj){

                    $("#toadMe").empty();
                    firstName = $(obj).siblings('firstName');
                    lastName = $(obj).siblings('lastName');
                    age = $(obj).siblings('age');
                    hometown = $(obj).siblings('hometown');
                    job = $(obj).siblings('job');

                    $('<h1></h1>').html(firstName).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(lastName).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(age).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(hometown).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(job).appendTo('#toadMe');

          }//update   
    //setInterval(itemContent,1500);

    function itemContent(q) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "people.xml"

        }).done(function (xml) {

            $(xml).find('fullName').each(function() {

                var fullName = $(this).text();

                if(q==fullName) {

                    $("#toadMe").empty();
                    firstName = $(this).siblings('firstName');
                    lastName = $(this).siblings('lastName');
                    age = $(this).siblings('age');
                    hometown = $(this).siblings('hometown');
                    job = $(this).siblings('job');

                    $('<h1></h1>').html(firstName).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(lastName).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(age).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(hometown).appendTo('#toadMe');
                    $('<h1></h1>').html(job).appendTo('#toadMe');
                }

            });

        }).fail(function (response, error) {

            $('#info').text('Error!');

        });

    };
```

Here is a fiddle. **http://jsfiddle.net/8xLk4/** Watch the last name. It will autoupdate.

Comment: Jack, that didn't seem to effect anything. Here is my live example: http://jamestarlton.x10.mx/LRU/   you can go to the admin page (u:admin p:admin), make a change, and you will see the button menu update automatically, but the content menu stays the same. This should help you get an actual idea of what my dilemma is. Thanks.

Comment: Panama Jack, the live example is using your script verbatim btw.

Comment: Jack, the UI is a little messy but you should be able to navigate to the admin page. Once you do that you can make a change to a record; I advise changing the first and or last name of an entry so you can see the button(s) autoupdate, also make a change to the other fields and you will see them not autoupdate.

Comment: I think I understand now. See if this works for you.

Comment: My first solution should work, but I believe there was a capitalization issue. It should be a capital N. itemContent(fullName). Try it now or you can do the 2nd one.

Comment: I saw that you got it solved another cool way. I actually had gotten it a few hours ago in chat, but I had the ID's in the wrong order that's why it wouldn't compare. After I realized it you got it solved. I was tired. LOL ughh.

Comment: Jack, I'm interested in seeing your solution too whenever you feel like posting it. Here is the syntax from my found solution: http://pastebin.com/6vRp4gB9